# Increase front-end message appearance time

Tags: magento2, javascript, timeout

I have the following Javascript code and need to increase the time that these 3 messages are displayed on the Magento2 front-end. Customers cannot see them as they flash.

```
define([
        'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select',
        'mage/translate'
    ], function (Column, $t) {
        'use strict';

        return Column.extend({
            defaults: {
                bodyTmpl: 'ui/grid/cells/html'
            },
            getLabel: function (record) {
                var columnVal = record.is_approved[0];

                if (columnVal === 'pending') {
                    return '<span class="grid-severity-notice" style="background:#fffbbb; color:#f38a5e; border-color: #f38a5e"><span>' + $t('Pending') + '</span></span>';
                } else if (columnVal === 'notapproved') {
                    return  '<span  class="grid-severity-minor"><span>' + $t('Not Approved') + '</span></span>';
                } else if (columnVal === 'approved'){
                    return  '<span class="grid-severity-notice"><span>' + $t('Approved') + '</span></span>';
                }

                return '';
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Would the `setTimeout` be an appropriate method for tackling this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do adjusting the timeout period on the file.

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js

Check lines 71/72 where you can set the time out.

**NOTE:**
Instade of modify the magento core files, please re-write this file into extension and then doing this things.